# Consume WCF REST service in SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, apps-development

How to consume the WCF REST service in a SHarePoint Hosted App? Please give me some examples through CuRD operation

Comment: You wand sharepoint wcf rest service or your owm custom WCF web service?

Comment: My own Custom WCFREST web service

Answer (score 0):

One key prerequisite to interacting with SharePoint lists items is to obtain the correct URI for the SharePoint site the list is hosted in. Once you have the correct base URI the next step is to determine the correct URI for the list with which you would like to interact.

For Create Operation:

```
function createListItemWithDetails(listName, siteUrl, title, success, failure) {

    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": title
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

For details please check: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx

For consuming Custom WCF REST API you can check:

http://www.silver-it.com/node/159